# How to Populate a Div Based on Javascript <script>?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using maxminds geoip script and I'm using

`<script>document.write( geoip_city() );</script>`

to display the users local city.  for me, this would be `New York`.  I usually don't have any issues with this script but when I include it within my fancybox modal the page only says "New York" in black text and the rest of the page is completely blank.

My question is how do I get the value of 
`<script>document.write( geoip_city() );</script>` and instead of pasting that directly into the fancybox modal, how do I get the value which is `New York` to print to a div such as

`<div class="userscity"></div>` that way wherever in the website that div/class is posted it will post the users city?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with code, then I'll give explanations:

```
<script>
    var geoipOutput = geoip_city();
    var element = document.querySelector(".userscity");
    element.innerHTML = geoipOutput;
</script>
```

Your javascript will always have to be in `<script>` tags.  The way you currently had it, you were just rewriting the whole document to be whatever is the result of the `geoip_city()` function.

Instead, I made a variable called geoipOutput.  I have no idea what comes out of your `geoip_city()` call, so this lets you save the output and tweak it if you want.  Or you can check if it equals "New York", and behave differently if it doesn't, or do anything else that jumps to mind.

Next, I find the div with the class you want.  Note that as per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/Document.querySelector), this will return the **first** div matching that selector.  If there's more than one, you would want to use `document.querySelectorAll` and loop on the answer.

Finally, I set that div's innerHTML property.  This should display it the way you want.

Comment: would this be used with `<div class="userscity"></div>`?

Comment: @JoeBobby Yes, this code assumes you have at least one element with a class of `userscity`.

Comment: it was clashing with some other scripts on the page but i got it working thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `geoip_city()` function returns a value, which in your case is "New York".  Currently, you are sending that value to the `document_write()` function, which will write "New York" to the end of the document.

To write that value to a specific div, you'll do something like this:

```
<script>
    var city = geoip_city();
    var div = document.querySelector(".usercity");
    div.innerText = city;
</script>
```

First, get the value of `geoip_city()`.

Then, find the element to put it into.  `querySelector` uses CSS-style selectors to find an element.

Finally, assign the value to the innerText property of your div.

If you want "New York" to appear inline with other text, use a span instead of a div to capture the value.

Comment: i tried `<span class="userscity"></span>`? but cant get anything to display i place the code you provided in the `<head>` and the other within content right?